# Spaces satisfying a strong Cartan-Hadamard theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a connected geodesic metric space.  When does there there exists a covering map $\pi:H\rightarrow X$ which is a *local-isometry* where $H$ is either a Hilbert space or a Euclidean space?

- **Strengthened:** If $(X,d)$ is simply connected and is the length space induced by a Riemannian geometry and if we only consider finite-dimensional $H$ then by [the classical Cartan-Hadamard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) we know that $(X,d)$ must be non-positive curvature.
- **Relaxed:** If instead we weaken the problem, so that H is only required to be Hadamard then $(X,d)$ must also be Hadamard (by the metric version of the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem).

However, what is know of $(X,d)$ if we specifically want $H$ to be Hilbert or Euclidean?

Comment: G should hae been H; a typo.  For $\pi$ indeed, I would ideally like it to be a local isometry.

Comment: It seems to me that you stated the Cartan-Hadamard theorem in the wrong direction (it states that non-positive curvature implies the universal cover is globally CAT(0)); but the other way round is obvious: curvature is a local property and thus is non-positive (resp. vanishes) whenever the same holds for the universal cover. So your spaces are flat.

Comment: For finite dimensional manifolds, the keyword is "Bierberbach's theorem".

Comment: Thanks a lot Benoit, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Hilbert spaces (of all dimensions finite or infinite) are the only geodesic spaces with extendable geodesics which are flat in the sense of Alexandrov.
Therefore $X$ has to have extendable geodesics + it has to be locally flat (in the sense of Alexandrov).
By Cartan--Hadamard theorem, these two conditions are also sufficient.

Comment: Since I had to google the definition, I'll mention it here for convenience: "A geodesic metric space is flat in the sense of Alexandrov if any geodesic triangle in X can be isometrically embedded in a Euclidean space."

Comment: @HJRW Can you pass a reference to this?

Comment: @PiotrK you may look at the intro to our book https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03483